# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method openEditor on channel video_editor_sdk)

Tags: arrays, flutter, video, uivideoeditorcontroller

**[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method openEditor on channel video_editor_sdk)**

My project in this error .

Use This Dependency : video_editor_sdk: ^2.6.0

Please fast This Error Solution .. **StackOverflow Community**

Comment: Stop and restart the app after you add packages which includes native platform functionality

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is only supported on `Android` or `iOS`. If you're testing on another platform it'll throw the `MissingPluginException`.

Always check `PLATFORM` in the package info on https://pub.dev. The image below is from [`video_editor_sdk`](https://pub.dev/packages/video_editor_sdk) package that says only `Android` or `iOS` are supported.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I Use this method but not Working

Comment: I've said this plugin is only supported by `Android` or `iOS`. Check PLATFORM in the image.

Comment: Bro not a This Matter But I Solved problem

Comment: It'd be nice if you answer yourself so other users facing the same problem can find the right answer.